# Resource Globalization using C# - Label and Error message

Tags: c#, globalization

I have implemented globalization using RESX files in my winform project using the .NET C# 4.7.2 framework. The current RESX files are used for Labels, now I need to have another resource file for Error messages.

I'm not sure how can I create different resource files "ABC.Error.Resources.cs-CZ.resx" and "ABC.Label.Resources.cs-CZ.resx" in the same project, as the resource DLL's are created for the respective language labels only.

My Solution structure is:

```
--Solution.sln
---Project.proj
----Resources(folder containing label resource files)
-----ABC.Label.Resources.cs-CZ.resx
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: You should read about [satellite assemblies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/create-satellite-assemblies)

Comment: @MarkBenningfield, how can I create two different files(Error message and Label message) for the same language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found two approaches to solve above-mentioned problem.

- approach 1

using "**CreateFileBasedResourceManager**" from "**ResourceManager**" class of .NET framework

step 1: Convert "**.RESX**" file to ".resources" file using "**resgen.exe**" from .NET framework.

[image: resgen]

Step 2: use below method to get the data from the resources file

```
static string ReadResourceValue(string file, string key)

        {

            string resourceValue = string.Empty;
            try
            {

                string resourceFile = file;

                string filePath =  "ConsoleApp1.en-GB.resources";

                ResourceManager resourceManager = ResourceManager.CreateFileBasedResourceManager(resourceFile, filePath, null);
                // retrieve the value of the specified key
                CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("en-IN");
                resourceValue = resourceManager.GetString(key, ci);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                resourceValue = string.Empty;
            }
            return resourceValue;
        }
```

- approach 2

using "**ResXResourceSet**" from **System.Resources** class of .NET framework.

```
static string ReadResourceFromFile()
        {
            string resxFile = "Resources\ConsoleApp1.en-GB.resx";
            string retValue = string.Empty;
            using (ResXResourceSet resxSet = new ResXResourceSet(resxFile))
            {
                // Retrieve the string resource for the title.
                retValue = resxSet.GetString("Test1");
            }
            return retValue;
        }
```

Hope this will help someone in future.